# Proof Verification: Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove that $b^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $ 0<b<1$

Proof by the ratio test:

$b^{n}/b^{n-1}$ = $b$ $ \to b<1$

$ \implies b^n \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$

Is this proof correct? Can anyone please verify it?

Comment: $\frac{b^n}{b^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{b}$

Comment: The edit has been made. It was a mistake. Is the proof ok now?

Comment: You've edited not what you need. If $\frac{1}{b^n} \to 0$ then $b^n \to \infty$

Comment: I've just realised the proof is completely wrong. 1/b > 0 because b is between 0 and 1 and hence, the ratio test won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct with slight modification.

You meant $$b^{n+1}/b^{n}=b\to b$$

$$b<1\implies $$

$$ lim _{n\to \infty} b_n =0$$

Which is correct by the ratio test for positive sequences.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!  I took $b^n/b^{n+1}$ rather than the other way round. Yes it works, THANK YOU!!

Comment: Thanks for your good solution. You have used the ratio test efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof isn't correct, because besides the monotonicity of your sequence you should also prove its boundness. 
As an another way, you can use the fact $b^n = e^{n \ln b}$ and $\ln b < 0$ hence $e^{n \ln b} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$0 <b <1 \implies \frac {1}{b}>1$$

put $$\frac {1}{b}=1+\epsilon . $$

Using the fact that
$$(1+\epsilon)^n\ge 1+n\epsilon $$
which we prove by induction, we get
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac {1}{b^n}=+\infty $$
and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}b^n=\frac {1}{+\infty}=0.$$